# What am I doing wrong with SQLite3 Python3

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

I can't figure out what the problem is. I am getting  following error message: 
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: Atm. This happens on line 34, which is the insertData function once it gets to cursor.execute(sql). Everything seems to be working fine, can anyone help with this?

This specifically crashes when I press "Y" to recreate my current table on line 14.

```
   import sqlite3
    import time

def create_table(dbName, table_name, sql):
    with sqlite3.connect('ATM.db') as db:
        cursor = db.cursor()
        cursor.execute("select name from sqlite_master where name=?",(table_name,))
        result = cursor.fetchall()
        keep_table = True
        if len(result) == 1:
            response = input("The table {0} already exists, do you wish to recreate it (y/n)".format(table_name))
            if response.lower() == "y":
                keep_table = False
                print("The {0} table will be recreated".format(table_name))
                cursor.execute("drop table if exists {0}".format(table_name))
                db.commit()
                insertData()
            else:
                print("The existing table was kept")
                insertData()
        else:
            keep_table = False
        if not keep_table:
            cursor.execute(sql)
            db.commit()
            insertData()


def insertData():
    with sqlite3.connect("ATM.db") as db:
        cursor = db.cursor()
        sql = """INSERT INTO Atm(Title, First, Surname, Balance) VALUES ('Mr.', 'Jeremy', 'Clarkson', 172.16),
                                                                        ('Miss', 'Suzanne', 'Perry', 15.62)"""
        cursor.execute(sql)
        db.commit()

db_name = "ATM.db"
sql = """ create table Atm
        (CustomerID integer,
        Title text,
        First text,
        Surname text,
        Balance real,
        primary key(CustomerID))"""
create_table(db_name, "Atm", sql)
```

sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: Atm

Comment: When you say "yes" to recreating the table - you drop it, but never recreate that table attempting prior to calling `insertData`... (you only do that at the very end once inside `if not keep_table`...). Looks like for now you could get away with adding `cursor.execute(sql)` straight after dropping the table but might be better to re-think your whole logic instead...

Comment: Ah yes, ofcourse. Thanks. It should work if I create an additional function within that section of "yes" that creates the table then goes to insertData.. Thank you.